# Enforce largest srcset image

Tags: wordpress, srcset

So my client was complaining that their images were blurry as hell despite uploading very crisp, retina images. Upon investigation, the culprit is WordPress' automatic `srcset` attributes.

I dunno if it's intended or not, but they just look *horrendous* on any screen size (on my 1440px screen, it's loading images at 300px wide for some reason).

At this point I'm no longer overly concerned *why*, I'd just like it to go away and enforce the 'large' size for everyone.

Is that achievable? If I disable it in functions.php, it still just loads the thumbnail-size image.

Comment: You can specify the image size i.e 'full','medium' & 'thumbnail' or else you can use your own defined sizes too.

Comment: Thanks Tristup. I understand that, but is there a way of overriding it? 

It's a tad out of scope to teach the client, then go through every post and adjust...